# Eclipse - Webserver autorun

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, wamp

I'd like to set some autorun task to Eclipse, or simply set the command with path, how to run my Apache while starting Eclipse.

My point is, that I don't want webserver (Apache) to be running after OS start, because it's useless load for my laptop. I usually want webserver use when I start Eclipse, so I think there could be an option, when can I do that to save my OS load and my time.

How can I set this?

Comment: Do you want it to autorun, or do you want it to be optional? You're ambiguous on that.

Comment: I want it autorun - after Eclipse start.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497589/eclipse-action-macros/4497844#4497844

Answer (score 0):

In the **Run**-menu, chose **Run Configurations...**

There you can configure your Apache webserver.

Then you can simply start your webserver from the Run-menu (Green, round play-button).

Added:

You could find out if Eclipse is started from a batch file/script. Then you should be able to add a line to this file to start Apache.

Comment: Thanks for advice, that could make it easier, but not really automatic. I want Apache run just after Eclipse start (with no action needed from me).