# Eclipse action/macros

Tags: eclipse

Does anybody know how to force Eclipse to do some actions after its starting?
e.g. to open a file, to click some menu item, to change properties in dialog etc.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: [Launch an action in Eclipse RCP at startup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2220586/60462)

Answer (score 0):

[Escripts](http://escripts.sourceforge.net/) is an eclipse scripting plugin. At [this](http://escripts.sourceforge.net/index.php/Escripts_Documentation#Starting_a_Scripted_Workbench) link you will see, that after [installing](http://escripts.sourceforge.net/index.php/Getting_Started) and creating your script, how you can have it executed by simply changing your shortcut you use to start eclipse.